# Make children stretch to fill their parent but display scrollbar for each child when overflowed

Tags: css, flexbox

I've got a view that has 3 columns that need to span the entire height of the view.

If the contents of each column don't take up the entire height of the view then I'd like there to not be a scrollbar for that column (though I still want a border on the left/right side of the column that spans the entire height of the view).

If the contents of a column do take up the entire height of the view (or overflow the view) then I'd like a scrollbar for each column that is overflowing its height.

So say if each column doesn't have many items, then there'd be no scrollbars. If column 2 is the only column with a lot of content then there might be only one scrollbar for the middle column. If all 3 columns have a lot of content and are overflowing the view then I'd like 3 independent scrollbars for each column.

Here's what I've got so far, but I can't seem to figure out how to get each column to get their own scrollbar rather than just the main scrollbar for the entire window.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkred;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.child-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.gran-child-item {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body class="parent">

  <div class="child-column">
    <h4> Left </h4>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="child-column">
    <h4> Center </h4>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="child-column">
    <h4> Right </h4>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

[Fiddle-1](https://jsfiddle.net/st61h9kd/1/)

**UPDATE**

The code above was a smaller piece of my entire website (I didn't want to make my example too complicated, but it appears it was too simple). I was hoping the header/sidebar/footer structure would play nice and I could just drop a solution in, but it appears I need to explain the whole website structure to get it to work... Like many websites, I have a header and sidebar that stay fixed to the top and side of my website, I also have a footer which needs to stay at the bottom of the page. The way I did this before was by putting `flex-grow: 1` on the main page content div and it'd force the footer to the bottom. It appears this now makes my page grow and not let the columns each have their own scrollbars.

Below is some revised code showing how I do the header/sidebar/footer and includes @Michaels edits, though it now doesn't do the column scrolling the way I'd like.

To add some more info: there are many different pages that are displayed on my website MOST all of the pages are long and expand past the height of my view and therefore have a single scrollbar on the right side of the page. What prompted my SO question was a new page I needed to add that has these 3 columns that all need their own scrollbars. So If the header/sidebar/footer can all be structure to support both kinds of page then that'd be great.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    color: white;
    background-color: darkred;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}

.page-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.page-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: darkblue;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header"> header </div>
    <div class="sidebar"> sidebar </div>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="column">
                <h4> Left </h4>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h4> Center </h4>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h4> Right </h4>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"> footer </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Fiddle-2](https://jsfiddle.net/k78ecnja/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Works with a few modifications:

```css
/* include padding and borders in length calculations */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkred;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* min-width: 100vw; */ /* unnecessary; container is block level
                             element and takes full width by default */
                             
  /* min-height: 100vh; */ /* if you make it min-height, container will
                              just expand with content and overflow
                              can't be triggered */
                               
  height: 100vh; /* new */
  
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */ /* unnecessary */
}

.child-column {
  height: 100%; /* new; full height of parent container */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.gran-child-item {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* disable default shrink behavior;
                     otherwise items shrink (vertically,
                     in this case) to avoid overflowing container */
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body class="parent">

  <div class="child-column">
    <h4> Left </h4>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="child-column">
    <h4> Center </h4>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="child-column">
    <h4> Right </h4>
    <div class="gran-child-item"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnkw2fep/)

Comment: this works great for the original snippet of code I provided. But it didn't quite work when I placed it into my larger website. I've placed more code in my question to show how my header/sidebar/footer are arranged as info.